# MongoDb Group BY MAX date and get field from this document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Look my problen hehe. I don't know how I can do it.
There are a lot of assetState 1..n I would like do aggregation for get last asset state group by asset.

Mongo collection : assetState

```
[
{
    "lsd" : {
     "$id" : ObjectId("lucas")
    },
    "stateDate" : ISODate("2018-09-10T16:26:44.501Z"),
    "assetId" : ObjectId("5b96b7645f2b3c0101520s60")
},
{
    "lsd" : {
     "$id" : ObjectId("denner")
    },
    "stateDate" : ISODate("2018-09-10T17:26:44.501Z"),
    "assetId" : ObjectId("5b96b7645f2b3c0101520s60")
},
{
    "lsd" : {
     "$id" : ObjectId("denner")
    },
    "stateDate" : ISODate("2018-09-10T18:26:44.501Z"),
    "assetId" : ObjectId("5b96b7645f2a8c0001530f61")
},
{
    "lsd" : {
      "$id" : ObjectId("lermen")
        }
    },
    "stateDate" : ISODate("2018-09-10T20:26:44.501Z"),
    "assetId" : ObjectId("5b96b7645f2a8c0001530f61")
},
{
    "lsd" : {
      "$id" : ObjectId("floripa")
    },
    "stateDate" : ISODate("2018-09-10T19:26:44.501Z"),
    "assetId" : ObjectId("5b96b7645f2a8c0001530f61")
}
]
```

I would like get max "stateDate", so I need get LSD from same row(document).

Expected result:

```
{
    "lsd" : {
      "$id" : ObjectId("lermen")
    },
    "stateDate" : ISODate("2018-09-10T20:26:44.501Z")
}
```

I tried to do:

```
db.getCollection('assetState').aggregate([
{
        $group: {
            "_id": {"assetId": "$assetId"},
            "stateDate": {
                "$max": "$stateDate"
            },
            "lsd":  {$last: "$lsd"} // I tried change $max to $min and $last it din't work :(

        }
]);
```

Result:

```
{
    "lsd" : {
      "$id" : ObjectId("floripa")
    },
    "stateDate" : ISODate("2018-09-10T20:26:44.501Z")
}
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
db.getCollection('assetState').aggregate([
{$sort:{"stateDate":-1}},
]).limit(1)
```

Comment: There are different assets. (assetId)
It isn't help me. Tks

Comment: Which lsd data are you want ??

Comment: I would like receive this result: {
    "lsd" : {
      "$id" : ObjectId("lermen")
    },
    "stateDate" : ISODate("2018-09-10T20:26:44.501Z")
}

Answer (score 0):

you can `$sort` descending before `$group` and gets the first item of each group with `$arrayElemAt`

```
db.getCollection('assetState').aggregate([
{ $sort: { stateDate: -1 } },
{ $group: { _id: { "assetId" : "$assetId" }, 
    states: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
},
{ $project: { "last_asset": { $arrayElemAt: [ "$states", 0 ] }, _id:0  } },
])
```

Result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "last_asset" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5db2b34fa1b70230bba9c4d9"),
        "lsd" : "denner",
        "stateDate" : ISODate("2018-09-10T17:26:44.501Z"),
        "assetId" : "5b96b7645f2b3c0101520s60"
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "last_asset" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5db2b34fa1b70230bba9c4db"),
        "lsd" : "lermen",
        "stateDate" : ISODate("2018-09-10T20:26:44.501Z"),
        "assetId" : "5b96b7645f2a8c0001530f61"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use $unwind (aggregation) 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Answer (score 0):

I have this for the group by phase:

```
{
 _id: {"sourceOfEvent":"$sourceOfEvent","vehicleId":"$vehicleId"},
  maxTimeOfEvent: { $max: "$timeOfEvent" }
}
```

So group by on 2 fields and I use the max to get the max of the timeOfEvent (which is a date)